# Treat Decimal as a Whole Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal

Is there a way for the total to be calculated by multiplying the costPerCan as a whole number rather than a decimal?

It appears as a whole number ('No. of Cans') using the Math.floor BUT if for example the 'No. of Cans' = 1 then the Total should = £18.23!

As it stands the canCount is being treated as a decimal in the equation?

```
$('input').keyup(function () { // run anytime the value changes


var width = parseFloat($('#width').val()); 
var height = parseFloat($('#height').val());
var SqMetresPerCan = parseFloat($('#per-can').val());
var costPerCan = parseFloat($('#cost').val());
var sizePerCan = parseFloat($('#size').val());

var canCount = width * height / SqMetresPerCan;

$('#added').html((canCount * costPerCan).toFixed(2));
$('#cans').html(Math.round(canCount.toFixed(2)));
```

all code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/523/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't buy part of a can, you have to round it up to the next highest whole number, so

```
var canCount = Math.ceil(width * height / SqMetresPerCan);
```

And once you have a whole number of cans, your total price will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You actually want to round the number of cans down to the lowest whole number (assuming that you have a container with dimensions width and height that you want to fit some number of cans into without going over) with Math.floor() when you first calculate it.

```
var canCount = Math.floor(width * height / SqMetresPerCan);
```

If you use Math.ceil as the other poster said, then you will calculate the number of cans that first exceeds the space provided.  I suppose that could be what you're after (or something else even), but you didn't describe your intent.

Now, if you are trying to pack cans into a container with certain dimensions, you've actually unlocked a much harder problem since [most] cans can only be one shape (round) and they won't squish to fill in the spaces between each other.  So there will be a lot of space that you can't use.

Please see this Wikipedia article for a discussion of packing algorithms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems

**However**, you have a variable "SqMetresPerCan," which *might* include padding for the can that forces it into a grid, making it a simpler problem, but still not as easy as the code snippet above.  additionally, that grid might have to be uniform, rendering fancy square-packing algorithms useless.

In this case, you would have to calculate the number of cans that fit into the 'width direction' and then the number of cans that fit into the 'height direction' and multiply them together.  If a can in the grid takes up x `SqMetresPerCan`, then its width and height will both be `Math.sqrt(x)`. For example, if a can has `SqMetresPerCan = 9`, then the length it takes up in each direction will be `Math.sqrt(9) = 3`.  Continuing with that example, if we have a container that is 1000x1 SQMetres, we couldn't be able to fit any cans since a can can't "squish" in either direction.  Conversely, if it was a 1000x3 container, it would fit 333 cans instead of 0 since the smallest dimension is now enough to fit a single can.  Taking this into consideration, an improved method for canCount is:

```
var canUnit = Math.sqrt(SqMetresPerCan)
var canCount = Math.floor(width/canUnit)*Math.floor(height/canUnit)
```

And then:

```
$('#added').html((canCount * costPerCan).toFixed(2));
$('#cans').html(canCount);
```

So what we did first was completely ignore `size`, since it's completely unclear how that's supposed to be used when we have `SqMetresPerCan`.  Then we calculate a single dimension of a can, assuming there is padding to "turn a circle into a square."  We weren't concerned with flooring here since we're just working with dimensions.  Then we calculate the number of cans that fit in each direction (by flooring the container dimension divided by the supposed dimension of the can in that direction) and multiply them together to get the total number of cans as an integer, which we can print right away with using toFixed.  Multiply that integer by `costPerCan` in order to get the total cost, which we should use `toFixed(2)` with since it's currency.

Comment: thank you for your effort, much appreciated: however my calculator is not a s complex as you have interpreted, much to my blame for not explaining my intent very well; It calculates the total cost and minimum number of cans needed to paint an area surface by width and height. if the number of cans is a whole and a fraction I need this number to round-up so it tells the customer what the minimum is required o paint their desired area.